# Real world example of getting value from std::future before std::thread::join is called

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread, stdasync

I start learning about `std::thread` and `std::future`, and wrote very trivial example (I wanted to get the value from `std::future` before `std::thread` ends):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    auto task = std::packaged_task<int (int, int)>{foo};
    auto future = task.get_future();
    
    auto t = std::thread{
        [&task](int a, int b)
        {
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    
            task(a, b);
    
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s); // something heavy to do
            std::cout << "Thread ends.\n";
        }, 1, 2
    };
    
    std::cout << future.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Waiting for thread\n";
    t.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Fisrtly, I wonder, if a real world example may be something like: logging, or saving something into database.

And secondly, if I cut out the `std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s)`, is there any point of using `std::thread` instead of `std::async`?

Comment: @NathanOliver In this case `future.get()` waits for `task` (i.e. `foo`) to complete -- not the thread itself.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: @G.M. Getting coffee, I really misread the code.

Comment: A typical real world use case might be a _thread pool_. There, you want to create a fixed number of threads and then possibly access the results of individual tasks via future objects.

Comment: ...thread pool..., In some thread pool implementations (in some languages. I don't know so much about C++) for each task submitted to the pool, the `submit` call returns a future, and the worker thread that performs the task eventually `complete`s the future after the task is done. The worker then, potentially, lives to perform other tasks and complete other futures.